# Disallow merging your own pull request on GitHub

Tags: github

We have a practice in our company that people can't merge their own pull requests. PRs are only allowed to be merged by reviewers.

What can we do on GitHub to enforce this?

Is there some way which would disallow people to merge their own pull request or is there something which will be a good alternative for this policy?

Comment: This is a question about GitHub and is not related to programming. You should probably ask the GitHub support team this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is there a better place on StackExchange for this question?

Comment: Probably not, I would ask GitHub support. For what it's worth, I don't believe this is possible, but I'm not an expert.

Comment: I disagree with the current close reason on this question: "This is a question about GitHub and is not related to programming. You should probably ask the GitHub support team this." GitHub can be considered to be a **software development tool**, so I consider it to be ***on-topic*** for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of policy is best managed in [GitHub Organizations](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations): it has a [richer set of permissions](https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-the-different-access-permissions).

You can define [teams](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-organization-members-to-a-team), and make the reviewer team the owner of the repo which accepts PR.

If you want the reviewer to not accept their own policy, then GitHub permissions wouldn't be enough, and you would need to put in place a listener able to alert you in that case (PR accepted by its author), using [GitHub API PR Events](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent).

Comment: It takes it further - They don't the reviewer team to accept their own PR.

Comment: @manojlds I agree. There isn't much more that GitHub can do, beside alert you when that happen. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Official response from Github team confirms this